# FeathersJS and MongoDB different results querying a field from HTTP GET and service.find in hooks

Tags: mongodb, feathersjs

I'm getting different response when querying a service from a specific field, depending on if I'm using CURL or running app.service().find() on the server. I'm using MongoDB, here's an example of my results.

```
// Here's a list of all data in the service
curl 'http://192.168.99.100:3030/players/'
[
    {"_id":"5a04bd4eee3648000fbad08f","userId":"59f8e18c14b066000ff63cbb","gameId":"5a04bd4eee3648000fbad08e","isHost":true,"handle":"dude"},
    {"_id":"5a0b41bbacd285000ffb310c","userId":"59f8e18c14b066000ff63cbb","gameId":"5a0b41bbacd285000ffb310b","isHost":true,"handle":"dude"},
    {"_id":"5a0b440aacd285000ffb310d","gameId":"5a0b41bbacd285000ffb310b"},
    {"_id":"5a0b44f7acd285000ffb310e","gameId":"5a0b41bbacd285000ffb310b"},
    {"_id":"5a0b498dc31cea000fef17dd","gameId":"5a0b41bbacd285000ffb310b","userId":"5a0b4117acd285000ffb310a","handle":"dog"},
    {"_id":"5a0b4a76c31cea000fef17de","gameId":"5a0b41bbacd285000ffb310b","userId":"5a0b4117acd285000ffb310a","handle":"dog"}
]}

// If I query on the gameId 5a0b41bbacd285000ffb310b from curl, it only returns 
// 4 of 5 rows skipping the first player
curl 'http://192.168.99.100:3030/players/?gameId=5a0b41bbacd285000ffb310b' 
[
    {"_id":"5a0b440aacd285000ffb310d","gameId":"5a0b41bbacd285000ffb310b"},
    {"_id":"5a0b44f7acd285000ffb310e","gameId":"5a0b41bbacd285000ffb310b"},
    {"_id":"5a0b498dc31cea000fef17dd","gameId":"5a0b41bbacd285000ffb310b","userId":"5a0b4117acd285000ffb310a","handle":"dog"},
    {"_id":"5a0b4a76c31cea000fef17de","gameId":"5a0b41bbacd285000ffb310b","userId":"5a0b4117acd285000ffb310a","handle":"dog"}
]}


// When I run this query server side passing gameID = 5a0b41bbacd285000ffb310b
// I only get the first created player in the list.
var gameID = hook.result._id;
app.service('players').find({
    query:{
      gameId: gameID,
    }
}).then(players => {
    console.log(players);
});
[
    {"_id":"5a0b41bbacd285000ffb310c","userId":"59f8e18c14b066000ff63cbb","gameId":"5a0b41bbacd285000ffb310b","isHost":true,"handle":"dude"}
]
```

My filters are blank, and the hooks don't remove data they just get the "handle" from the userId.

It seems like the query might not work because there may be a difference in datatype. As in the fieldname gameId or the data stored.

The first ID in Players 5a0b41bbacd285000ffb310c was given the gameId from the server side after the game object was created using a hook. Like this:

```
// This hook is run after a new game is created
return function joinNewGame (hook) {
    var userid = hook.params.user._id;
    var gameid = hook.result._id;

    return hook.app.service('players').create({
            userId: userid,
            gameId: gameid,
            isHost: true,
        }).then(player => {

            return hook;
        });
};
```

The other players were written in a post request where gameId was passed as a string.

```
curl 'http://192.168.99.100:3030/players/' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{ "gameId":"5a0b41bbacd285000ffb310b"}'
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After some additional testing I find that it's a typing error. The typeof gameId for the server side created entry was "Object" while the client side was "String".

So my current fix is to cast the id's to strings before storing / querying from the server. Is this the best way to do Many to One relationships in the ORM? The [Docs](https://docs.feathersjs.com/faq/readme.html#how-do-i-do-associations) doesn't go into detail.

**Update:** Here's a different fix, I created a new hook that converts string to a MongoDB Object ID when storing the data, pass the fields that need to be updated in an array.

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

module.exports = function (fields, options = {}) { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  return function stringToObjectId (hook) {
    // For each passed field
    for(var i = 0; fields.length > i; i++){
      // Test if there's queries on the field, then convert
      if(hook.params.query && typeof hook.params.query[fields[i]] != "Object"){
        hook.params.query[fields[i]] = ObjectID(hook.params.query[fields[i]]);
      }
      // Test if there's data on the field, then convert
      if(hook.data && typeof hook.data[fields[i]] != "Object"){
        hook.data[fields[i]] = ObjectID(hook.data[fields[i]]);
      }
    }
    return Promise.resolve(hook);
  };
};
```

Comment: Yes. Mongoose handles those conversions already but if you are using MongoDB directly you will have to convert ObjectIds to strings and vice versa (e.g. cast the `hook.params.query.uerId` field to an ObjectId in a `before` hook). The irritating part here is probably that the JSON version of a MongoDB ObjectId will come back as a string.